# How to start new operation in Python

Tags: python, calculator, new-operator, calculation

So i have a simple calculator in **Python**. So what it does is, asks for an operation (like addition) and it asks for *first number* and *second number*.

> Lets say i choose **addition**,

> **first number:** 1

> **second number:** 1

> **result:** 2

And after that i want it to ask: **type {x} to start new calculation**

When you type x it basically restarts everything so you can do a different calculation. ( {x} could be anything i don't mind)

**How do i do that?**

current code:

```
print("Which operation do you want to do?")
print("Type + for addition")
print("Type - for subtraction")
print("Type * for multiplication")
print("Type / for division")

op = input('Enter your choice here = ')


if op == '+' :
  num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
  num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
  add = num1 + num2

  print("{0} + {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, add))


elif op == '-' :
  num1 = float(input("Enter the first number here: "))
  num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
  sub = num1 - num2

  print("{0} - {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, sub))


elif op == '*' :
  num1 = float(input("Enter the first number here: "))
  num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
  multi = num1 * num2

  print("{0} * {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, multi))


elif op == '/' :
  num1 = float(input("Enter the first number here: "))
  num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
  division = num1 / num2

  print("{0} / {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, division))


else :
  print("something went wrong!")
```

Comment: use a `while True` loop around all your operations. And break it if something other than x is pushed

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    print("Which operation do you want to do?")
    print("Type + for addition")
    print("Type - for subtraction")
    print("Type * for multiplication")
    print("Type / for division")
    print("Type 0 to exit")

    op = input('Enter your choice here = ')

    if op == '+' :
        while True:
            num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
            num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
            add = num1 + num2
            print("{0} + {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, add))

            again = input("Would you like to add two other numbers? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
            if again == 'Y':
                continue
            else:
                break


    elif op == '-' :
        while True:
            num1 = float(input("Enter the first number here: "))
            num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
            sub = num1 - num2
            print("{0} - {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, sub))
            again = input("Would you like to subtract two other numbers? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
            if again == 'Y':
                continue
            else:
                break


    elif op == '*' :
        while True:
            num1 = float(input("Enter the first number here: "))
            num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
            multi = num1 * num2
            print("{0} * {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, multi))
            again = input("Would you like to multiply two other numbers? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
            if again == 'Y':
                continue
            else:
                break


    elif op == '/' :
        while True:
            num1 = float(input("Enter the first number here: "))
            num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
            division = num1 / num2
            print("{0} / {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, division))
            again = input("Would you like to divide two other numbers? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
            if again == 'Y':
                continue
            else:
                break

    elif op == '0':
        print("Good bye!")
        break
    else :
        print("something went wrong!")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can place the code inside a function and then call the function within a while loop, the second input `again` is used to break the loop once the user is finished

```
print("Which operation do you want to do?")
print("Type + for addition")
print("Type - for subtraction")
print("Type * for multiplication")
print("Type / for division")


def function(op):
    if op == '+' :
        num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
        add = num1 + num2
    
        print("{0} + {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, add))
    
    
    elif op == '-' :
        num1 = float(input("Enter the first number here: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
        sub = num1 - num2
    
        print("{0} - {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, sub))
    
    
    elif op == '*' :
        num1 = float(input("Enter the first number here: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
        multi = num1 * num2
    
        print("{0} * {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, multi))
    
    
    elif op == '/' :
        num1 = float(input("Enter the first number here: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number here: "))
        division = num1 / num2
    
        print("{0} / {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, division))
    
    
    else:
        print("something went wrong!")

while True:
    op = input('Enter your choice here = ')
    function(op)
    again = input('Enter X to start new calculation: ')
    if again.lower() != 'x':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to do this. Use boolean variable repeat to decide if the user wants to do another calculation. If user input is 'x' repeat remains true and the calculator is restarted, but if user inputs anything else repeat is False and the loop exits:

```
repeat = True
while repeat:
    #Your code here
    again = input('type x to start new calculation')
    repeat = again in ['x', 'X']
```